# An issue with Dictionary and ArrayList

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

I have a Dictionary where RFile is a class, this dictionary holds all data that will be displayed in a listview.

The issue is this: The program will get the RFile class from the dictionary using a key obtained from the associated listViewItem and then add it to an ArrayList

```
ArrayList Files = new ArrayList();
Foreach (ListViewItem lvi in LV.Groups[1].Items)
     {
          Files.Add(Dict[lvi.tag]);
     }
```

Then the Files in the ArrayList is sent by VALUE (didn't put Ref in the method identifier) to a method that will process them and make some changes to the entries in the Files ArrayList, However these changes are also applying to the original Dictionary (And i don't the values there to be changes)

All i know is that i am not passing any data by reference unless that when getting a value from the dictionary using a key is done by reference.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: When you do `Files.Add(Dict[lvi.tag])` you are actually only adding a reference to the object associated with `lvi.tag` in your dictionary. You will have to make a copy of the object if you don't want changes to propagate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are always passed by reference, even if you don't use the ref-keyword.

You can implement the ICloanable-interface and clone your objects, so the changeds don't affect the original objects:

```
ArrayList Files = new ArrayList();
Foreach (ListViewItem lvi in LV.Groups[1].Items)
{
          Files.Add(Dict[lvi.tag].Clone());
}
```

and

```
public class RFile : ICloanable{
//Your RFile-code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that a class data is shared between all instances, i never knew that. I was wondering (just to learn more) is there another way to do the clone without adding an interface?

Comment: You could of course define your own method to clone an object, but the ICloanable interface is the default way of doing it. You can read about IClonable at the MSDN-library http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much, my issue was solved thanks to you. I decided to to define my own clone method. 

Again thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a tutorial about `ValueTypes` and `ReferenceTypes`.

Being said that `RFile` is a class then any changes to `RFile` instance will be reflected in all other places where it shares the same `RFile` instance since it is a "Reference type", no matter you pass it as `ref` or not.

Purpose of `ref` keyword is different and that's beyond the point of this question. You may need to understand about `ref` keyword too.

Here is a good resource about [Value type vs Reference type](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)